# vs 2013 portable class library windows.props not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library

In visual studio 2013 update 2 RTM if I do file new project, Portable Class library, asking for .NET 4.5 and Silverlight 5 targets I get this error on build

**Error 1   File 'Windows.props' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Portable&o2=7.0 for more information.  PCL**

The link is a dead link

I'm building and developing on a windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server box

The same project on windows 7 builds fine.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Very hard to explain, that file doesn't get used for PCL builds.  I can only recommend using SysInternals' Process Monitor and compare traces between the good and bad machine.

Comment: Did a compare with the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1 libraries from one box to other and seems some were missing on server. sync'd them and we seem ok now. V strange as clean install. Thanks for you help Hans

Comment: Hmya, why on Earth would you use a Windows Phone library when you don't target it?

Comment: Beats me, i didn't requiest it yet it still seems to need it

Comment: In the .csproj file that is created, what is the TargetFrameworkProfile property set to?

Comment: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile24</TargetFrameworkProfile>

Answer (score 1):

Did a compare with the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1 libraries from one box to other and seems some were missing on server. sync'd them and we seem ok now. V strange as clean install.